# Unable to append ajax XML response values to a select list

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm unable to append the response, i.e, the address tags to my select list.

I tried the `$(.each)` function but still could not achieve it.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
/*Ajax request to get list of address*/
$.ajax({
    url : url + 'Customer/get_address_list',
    data :{
        projectId : 1
    },
    dataType : 'xml',
    contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    crossDomain : true,
    timeout : 10000,
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('address').each(function(){
            var value = $(this).text();
            $("#address").append("<option " + value + "</option>");
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12  columns">
    <select id="address" name="address" class="col-lg-12  columns"  >
    </select>
</div>
```

Server response:

```
<addressList>
    <address>100East</address>
    <address>100KennedyEast</address>
    <address>100BoulevardEast</address>
    <address>110KennedyBoulevardEast</address>
    <address>1002BoulevardEast</address>
    <address>3002KennedyBoulevardEast</address>
    <address>17002BoulevardEast</address>
    <address>1802KennedyBoulevardEast</address>
    <address>2084BoulevardEast</address>
    <address>8804KennedyBoulevardEast</address>
    <listException>false</listException>
    <listExceptionId>0</listExceptionId>
    <listSize>10</listSize>
    <nextPage>false</nextPage>
    <pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
    <totalPages>0</totalPages>
    <totalRecords>0</totalRecords>
</addressList>
```

Comment: what is the generating html you're getting or error, if any. also, did you notice that your `option` opening tag is missin `>`?

Comment: no problem with syntax for option tag..i closed and check still same.. no errors , but i would like to append that response values to to my html select tag

Comment: The server response you posted is it coming from ajax call? or you know that it's going to be like that from some document etc? in short, what response is your ajax returning if you put `console.log(xml)` after `success : function(xml) {` <- this line?

Comment: response is coming from ajax. console.log(xml) returns the above response code

Answer (score 0):

hmm..i am not sure where the problem lies at this point. the code seems to be fine. maybe it's something related to parsing of xml.
May i suggest the use of `$.parseXML`? **[jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)**.

*UPDATE:*
i am not sure, but i think the problem could be that you're trying to use $.find method on a response coming from server. it's not a jquery object, nor it is a html dom, so i am not sure if using `$(xml)` will generate a jquery object that you can call `find` on.